# Trouble with encoding latin1 with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, warnings, input-encodings

I am having a little trouble with `biblatex` package. When I try to compile (with pdflatex) the following WARN message is being returned:

```
Process started: biber.exe AuxDirectory/"example"

INFO - This is Biber 2.12
INFO - Logfile is 'AuxDirectory/example.blg'
INFO - Reading 'AuxDirectory/example.bcf'
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'example.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'example.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'pt-BR' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'pt-BR' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'none/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'none' and locale 'pt-BR'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'pt-BR'
INFO - Writing 'AuxDirectory/example.bbl' with encoding 'latin1'
WARN - The entry 'Adam2009' has characters which cannot be encoded in 'latin1'.
       - Recoding problematic characters into macros.
WARN - The entry 'Adam2010' has characters which cannot be encoded in 'latin1'.
       - Recoding problematic characters into macros.
INFO - Output to AuxDirectory/example.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 2

Process exited normally
```

I have used the following minimal code for my the tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}%
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,sortlocale=auto,bibencoding=auto,backref=true,date=year]%
{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[english,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{247mm}{160mm}{*}
\setulmargins{3cm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\frenchspacing
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \cite{Adam2009}
    \cite{Adam2010}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Below, I also present minimal bib-code with the problematic two references.

```
@Article{Adam2009,
  author    = {Adam, C. and Klimas, P. and S{\'a}nchez-Guill{\'e}n, J. and Wereszczy{\'n}ski, A.},
  title     = {Compact baby Skyrmions},
  journal   = {Physical Review D},
  year      = {2009},
  volume    = {\bfseries 80},
  issue     = {10},
  month     = {11},
  pages     = {105013},
  doi       = {10.1103/PhysRevD.80.105013},
  url       = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevD.80.105013},
  urldate   = {2019-01-31},
  numpages  = {14},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
}


@Article{Adam2010,
  author       = {Adam, C. and Roma{\'n}czukiewicz, T. and S{\'a}nchez-Guill{\'e}n, J. and Wereszczy{\'n}ski, A.},
  title        = {Investigation of restricted baby Skyrme models},
  journaltitle = {Phys.ical Review D},
  year         = {2010},
  volume       = {\bfseries 81},
  number       = {8},
  month        = {4},
  pages        = {085007},
  doi          = {10.1103/PhysRevD.81.085007},
  url          = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevD.81.085007},
  urldate      = {2019-01-31},
  numpages     = {10},
  publisher    = {American Physical Society},
}
```

Apparently, the problem occurs because of the `{\'n}` character cannot be encoded in '`latin1`'. I trying to change the code, but without success. I will stay truly grateful if somebody to know as of solving this problem.

Comment: try to use `utf8` encoding, i.e.: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: @Zako, thank you for sugestion, but I still want to use latin1.

Comment: why? `utf8` contain all what have `latin1` (which is deprecated) and defined all what you report that are missed in `latin1` ...

Comment: Because I am using the tex studio and Scientific Workplace 5.5 simultaneously. For do not have encoding problem I need to use latin1.

Comment: well, than you should wait on other (not so simple) solution ... and further struggle with compatibility issue between used document writing systems (i wouldn't use nothing else than LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message is just a warning, and it is one that can be safely ignored if you have decided that taking action (i.e. using `utf8` instead of `latin1`) is not worth it for you (let me add that I absolutely think that encoding everything in UTF-8 would be the best solution here, but you'll have your reasons).

The warning occurs because *ń* is not contained in Latin-1 and thus can only be exported as a LaTeX macro combination instead of the real character if you insist on Latin-1 (in fact Biber is a bit more radical than probably necessary here: it will write out the entire entry with ASCII-macros and not only the offending character). This is independent of the input of the characters since Biber transforms everything to UTF-8 internally to be able to do sorting. It is only concerned with how the character is written to the `.bbl` file for further processing with `biblatex`.

You can avoid the warning by calling Biber with the option `--output-safechars`, i.e.

```
biber --output-safechars <filename>
```

This will leave all non-ASCII chars in macro form and will not attempt to convert any characters into the non-ASCII range of Latin-1. (So you would see a difference in the `.bbl` if you had an entry with all Latin-1 characters.)

---

Note that

```
volume    = {\bfseries 80},
```

is not very semantic. Try

```
volume    = {80},
```

with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}% volume of a journal
```

instead.